# How can I draw multiple semi-transparent rectangles on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rect

I have an image on a canvas and I want to draw semi-transparent rectangles on it. I draw them progressively by dragging and dropping with one finger.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
...

function handleTouch(event) {
    if (event.targetTouches.length === 1) {
      touch = event.targetTouches[0];

      if (event.type == 'touchmove') {
        if (drag) {
          rect.w = touch.pageX - rect.startX;
          rect.h = touch.pageY - rect.startY ;
          draw();
        }
      } else {
        rect.startX = touch.pageX;
        rect.startY = touch.pageY;
        drag = true;
      }
    }
}

function handleEnd(event) {
    drag = false;
}

function draw() {
    drawImageOnCanvas();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}

function drawImageOnCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
}
```

Right now it works well for one rectangle at a time and it looks like what I want, but I want more. How should I go about it?

Comment: @Huey because I `clearRect`, I can't just do that (and I have to do `clearRect` because it's semi-transparent rectangles).

Comment: @CassidyWilliams I don’t understand why you have to do `clearRect` if it’s semi-transparent. You can simply [`strokeRect` and `fillRect` another rectangle](http://jsfiddle.net/r466qr0t/) without `clearRect`. Could you elaborate on your exact use case and perhaps post a JSFiddle?

Comment: Ah my apologies @Xufox, just updated the description. It's because I'm progressively drawing the rectangles with touch.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams Ah, now I understand! Good question! You should explicitely include the fact that you’re progressively drawing the rectangle (from the comment) in your actual question, though.

Comment: @Xufox Updated. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: As I think of other software that does this, my guess is that other software would draw the rectangle on a different “layer” or in the context of HTML5 on a different Canvas above the original one. Another option is to generate and modify an HTML `<div>` over the original Canvas and on `touchleave` actually draw that rectangle on the Canvas as the `<div>` gets deleted / invisible. At least that wold be the safest approach.

Comment: _THE_ Cassidy Williams? Well I never!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it not possible to just keep an array of rects and then iterate over them since you need to redraw it every time?

```
...
var rects = [];

function handleTouch(event) {
    if (event.targetTouches.length === 1) {
      touch = event.targetTouches[0];

      if (event.type == 'touchmove') {
        if (drag) {
          rects[rects.length-1].w = touch.pageX - rect.startX;
          rects[rects.length-1].h = touch.pageY - rect.startY ;
          draw();
        }
      } else {
        rects.push({
          startX: 0,
          startY: 0,
          w: 0,
          h: 0
        });
        rects[rects.length-1].startX = touch.pageX;
        rects[rects.length-1].startY = touch.pageY;
        drag = true;
      }
    }
}

function handleEnd(event) {
    drag = false;
}

function draw() {
    drawImageOnCanvas();
    for (var i in rects) {
      var rect = rects[i];
      ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
      ctx.strokeRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 100, 255, 0.1)';
      ctx.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
    }
}

function drawImageOnCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution if only one Canvas element is used… but I think the performance cost will get quite high as the number of rectangles increases, won’t it?

Comment: It would, but if the canvas is being cleared, information of every rectangle needs to be retained, so I don't think there's any other way to accomplish it. If performance starts to suffer (which I don't think it would unless you have a very large number of rectangles), then it probably would need to be restructured so the canvas wasn't clearing.